# Input type number field accepting alphabets instead of numbers in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I have some issues with `input[type="number"]` in firefox and internet explorer. Typing characters would be number but text also typing in firefox and IE. Working perfect in chrome. Is it possible to fix without using `javascript`. Thanks in advance

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="mob_num" required="required" placeholder="(999)457-8454"/>
```

Comment: People are interesting in finding duplicate than answering.. Read my problem properly and mark as duplicate

Comment: Duplicate link doesn't solve my problem. Is it possible to use numbers rather than alphabets in input field without using javascript.

Comment: Reopened your question. And to solve that issue you need script since it is only webkit-based browsers (at least today) that block any other character than a number

Comment: Can You Tell Me IE version?

Comment: Okay lgson..   IE version 11 @shankar shastri

Answer (score 0):

If you add a validation error for non phone number characters, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Any possible rather than using js

Comment: Every browser implements as they please... Why not use javascript?

Comment: No problem by using js. Just ask for possibilities through html,css